# Debugging WebApp in VS for IE7, IE8 and IE9

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, code-behind, application-server

I have source for Webapplication in one machine. Developed with VS2010.
On this machine (machine1) I have IE9 installed. Note that the machine1 does not have IIS installed.

I want to test the application and debug into the application with IE7 or IE8. The only way I can do this is by using some other machine (machine2) that has IE7 or IE8 installed. But when I launch the webapp from the VS2010 the webapp runs on ASP.NET Development Server.

I can only access the webapp from only machine1. How do I make the webapp accessible from machine2? I need this to debug into codebehind for IE7, IE8 and IE9.

Help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it enough just to change IE 9 into compatibility mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change IE 9 to work in compatibility mode, by pressing F12 key... there are two menus: `Browser Mode` and `Document Mode` that you can change to make IE 9 *simulate* the behavior of IE 8 and IE 7.

The server does not care about what version of IE you are running... unless you are reading information about wich browser did the request. In that case I think IE 9 compatibility mode is going to work just fine... **I mean IE 9 can simulate the exact behavior of IE 8 and IE 7**.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the excellent [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) tool. This allows you to test your websites in IE9 through to IE5.5.